# Why was this Epsilon rendered this way?

Tags: math-mode

I'm using Freeplane to create a mind map. I've been using TeX to organize definitions etc. I typed in the following code:

```
$ \sigma(k): \k \in \mathbb{N} $
```

and was returned with this:

[image: What gives?]

Comment: Replace `\k` by `k`, The former is a diacritic.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @cgnieder Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `k` instead of `\k`:

```
$ \sigma(k): k \in \mathbb{N} $
```

**Remarks**

- You don't need to escape letters from the Latin/English alphabet in math mode. So, for a `k` in math mode, just write `$k$` or similar (what you did in `\sigma(k)`, without a backlash).
- `\k` is an *ogonek*, the hook you're seeing under `\in`. [Here's a list with other shortcuts in LaTeX.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! (Totally missed the escaped k!)